# When is the _id index used?

Tags: index, mongodb

**When is the `_id` index used** by MongoDB?

I could not find anything specific about it in [Index Introduction](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/), [Analyze Query Performance](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/), and [Query Plans](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/#read-operations-query-optimization).

When sorting by `_id` at the end of the query via `.sort({_id: -1})`, `.explain()` explicitly shows the index use. It might be that it is implicitly used in every `COLLSCAN` operation, though.

So is it just a normal index that is only accessed when sorting/querying by `_id`, or does it have hidden uses not shown by `.explain()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When sorting by _id at the end of the query via .sort({_id: -1}), .explain() explicitly shows the index use. It might be that it is implicitly used in every COLLSCAN operation, though.

A COLLSCAN operation is a collection scan, which indicates that no index is being used and the collection is being iterated in [natural order](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/).

If your query had no criteria but requested a sort by `_id`, the `_id` index would be the best candidate to return results in the expected order. In MongoDB 3.0 I would expect this to be indicated as an IXSCAN rather than a COLLSCAN.

> So is it just a normal index that is only accessed when sorting/querying by _id

As you suspected, the `_id` index is just a normal index which is a candidate for being selected by the query planner when querying and/or sorting by `_id`.

> does it have hidden uses not shown by .explain()

The [`explain()` results](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/) shows relevant query planning information, but by default only include a summary of the winning plan. You can see more detailed information (such as the candidate plans evaluated) using `.explain(true)`.

MongoDB 3.0's `explain()` actually has 3 verbosity modes:

- `queryPlanner`: default
- `executionStats`: more info on the winning plan
- `allPlansExecution` (aka `true`): information on all plans

There are some other uses of the `_id` index which aren't exactly hidden but may not be obvious:

- replication requires a unique `_id` index (historical note: in versions prior to MongoDB 2.2 it was possible to create and replicate capped collections without an `_id` index).
- a [`snapshot` cursor](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/#cursor.snapshot) iterates a collection in `_id` order to ensure a query will not return a document multiple times.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually meant `explain(true)`, but did not clearly write that. (Probably makes no sense to edit it now, though. You've addressed it, so that people would wonder if the question was edited).

Answer (score 3):

> In MongoDB, documents stored in a collection require a unique _id
>   field that acts as a primary key. MongoDB uses ObjectIds as the
>   default value for the _id field if the _id field is not specified;
>   i.e. if a document does not contain a top-level _id field, the MongoDB
>   driver adds the _id field that holds an ObjectId. In addition, if the
>   mongod receives a document to insert that does not contain an _id
>   field, mongod will add the _id field that holds an ObjectId.

```
ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
a 3-byte machine identifier,
a 2-byte process id, and
a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
```

MongoDB clients should add an _id field with a unique ObjectId. Using ObjectIds for the _id field provides the following additional benefits:

- In the mongo shell, you can access the creation time of the ObjectId,
  using the getTimestamp() method.
- Sorting on an _id field that stores
  ObjectId values is roughly equivalent to sorting by creation time.

Alternatives- 
The following are common options for storing values for _id:

- Use an ObjectId.
- Use a natural unique identifier, if available. This saves space and avoids an additional index.
- Generate an auto-incrementing number. See Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field.
- Generate a UUID in your application code. For a more efficient storage of the UUID values in the collection and in the _id index, store the UUID as a value of the BSON BinData type.
- Index keys that are of the BinData type are more efficiently stored in the index if:
  the binary subtype value is in the range of 0-7 or 128-135, and
  the length of the byte array is: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 20, 24, or 32.
- Use your driver’s BSON UUID facility to generate UUIDs. Be aware that driver implementations may implement UUID serialization and deserialization logic differently, which may not be fully compatible with other drivers. See your driver documentation for information concerning UUID interoperability.

for more detail- 
[See MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)